# Slice tuples within a list (python)

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, list-comprehension, slice

Suppose you have a `list of tuples` like this:

```
list_of_tuples = 
    [('11','12','13'),('21','22','23'),('31','32','33'),('41','42','43')]
```

Now I want to slice this list, or the tuples, so that I have (a new) list, with only the first two entries of each tuple. So, I want to get this:

```
new_list = [('11','12'),('21','22'),('31','32'),('41','42')]
```

My first attempt was some syntax like `new_list = list_of_tuples[:][0:2]`. The first brackets `[:]` indexing the entire list and `[:2]` taking element 0 and 1 of each tuple. However, this always *returns the first two tuples, containing all three original entries*. (So, I get `[('11','12','13'),('21','22','23')]`).

Why is it not working like this, and what is the underlying pythonic behavior here? I also noted, it does not matter how may `[:][:][:]` I write.

One way to get my desired results is by writing a list comprehension like this `new_list = [(t[0], t[1]) for t in list_of_tuples]`, but this requires substantially more code and I considered my original approach pythonic as well.

Comment: `lst[:]` slices the list, but without specifying any indices, in effect you're just making a copy of the list -- so `list_of_tuples[:][0:2]` is similar to `list_of_tuples[:2]` -- and it should be clear why *this* doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: `[:]` returns whole list out of which you slice the first 2 items

Comment: print [(a[0],a[1]) for a in list] try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt is doing this:

```
new_list = list_of_tuples[:] # Copy of the list
list_of_tuples[:][0:2] # element 0 to 2 of the copy.
```

Thus, you get the 2 first element of list_of_tuples:

```
[('11','12','13'),('21','22','23')]
```

That's jsut how python works ^^'

EDIT: And if you put several `[:]` you're just "copying" several time the original list, that's why it doesn't matter how many of this you place...

Comment: This is not what is asked, it is asking for every tuple only 2 elements should be there.

Comment: @AstikAnand He is asking for the explanation. He already has the solution with the list comprehension.

Comment: But this is not what is expected.

Comment: @AstikAnand Yes... He is asking why his attempt failed. That's the explanation of the fail.  (He commented this on a now deleted post).

Answer (score 3):

Your logic will not work because slicing does not operate on each sublist within a list. It will only operate on the outer list.

You can use a list comprehension instead:

```
new_list = [i[:2] for i in list_of_tuples]
```

Or, for a functional solution, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

new_list = list(map(itemgetter(0, 1), list_of_tuples))

print(new_list)

[('11', '12'), ('21', '22'), ('31', '32'), ('41', '42')]
```

The syntax you are looking for is akin to NumPy array indexing. NumPy is a 3rd party library which allows indexing by multiple dimensions simultaneously:

```
import numpy as  np

arr = np.array(list_of_tuples).astype(int)
res = arr[:, :2]

print(res)

[[11 12]
 [21 22]
 [31 32]
 [41 42]]
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question best, as it shows that this thinking is not totally wrong, but it just does not work with vanilla Python, only with NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply slice the tuple in your first list. Similar to:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('11','12','13'),('21','22','23'),('31','32','33'),('41','42','43')]
>>> new_list = [item[:2] for item in list_of_tuples]
>>> new_list
[('11', '12'), ('21', '22'), ('31', '32'), ('41', '42')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[(x, y) for x, y, _ in list_of_tuples]
```

Or a slicing with list-comprehension:

```
[x[:2] for x in list_of_tuples]
```

**Output**:

```
[('11', '12'), ('21', '22'), ('31', '32'), ('41', '42')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as well using lambda and map function

```
new_list  = list(map(lambda x:x[:2],your_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing iteration into list for tuple slicing a specific items:

**Code Syntax**

```
list =  [('11','12','13'),('21','22','23'),('31','32','33'),('41','42','43')]

new_list = [(a[0],a[1]) for a in list]
```

**Output**

```
[('11', '12'), ('21', '22'), ('31', '32'), ('41', '42')]
```